# How to use `this` in a function called by an ES6 arrow function?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6

I understand (I think) that arrow functions in ES6 use [Lexical this](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis), but I'm not sure why a function called by a fat arrow function would have `this` set as undefined.

What do I have to do to be able to call `this.setResult` in `handleAuthResult`? I do not want to use the old `function () {}.bind(this)` if I don't need to.

```
"use strict";

class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.checkAuth();
    }

    checkAuth() {
        document.write("Checking auth now. ");
        var iid = setInterval(() = > {
            if (true) { // Have to do some dumb check here
                clearInterval(iid);
                this.authenticate(this.handleAuthResult)
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    authenticate(callback) {
        callback({
            value: true
        });
    }

    handleAuthResult(result) {
        document.write(`The result is ${result.value}.`);
        this.setResult(result, this.loadThePage)
        // ^ `this` is undefined here. How can I ever set the result?
    }

    // Another asynchronous thing
    setResult(result, callback) {
        callback();
    }

    loadThePage() {
        document.write("The code never gets here, but the page should load now. ");
    }
};
var example = new Example();
```

Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/vujev4dj/

**Edit:** in my defense of this being marked as duplicate, the behaviour I expected *does* work in the following fiddle, which is why I expected to not have to use the `bind` function on `this.handleAuthResult` in ES6: https://jsfiddle.net/m9e7j4ds/

Comment: The reason it worked in the fiddle is because it uses `React.createClass()` instead of using ES6 classes (extending `React.Component`). `React.createClass()` binds all methods, which doesn't happen when using ES6 classes.

Comment: @bergi I don't agree that this is a duplicate of the question you linked, because it is not about ways to bind methods to ES6 class instances. Especially, making an arrow function directly one the class is not mentioned in the answers. I believe that is what the asker was looking for, although the question could be more well posed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is `undefined` in `handleAuthResult` because `handleAuthResult` isn't an arrow function and thus doesn't have lexical `this`. It's a normal prototype function (loosely, "method") which means that `this` is defined by how it's called.

The way you're calling it:

```
authenticate(callback) {
    callback({
        value: true
    });
}
```

doesn't set `this` to anything specific, so `this` is `undefined` (because you're in strict mode).

To fix it, either pass `this` into `authenticate` and use it:

```
this.authenticate(this.handleAuthResult, this)
```

and

```
authenticate(callback, thisArg) {
    callback.call(thisArg, {
        value: true
    });
}
```

or use `Function#bind` to create a function that, when called, will call `handleAuthResult` with the correct `this`:

```
this.authenticate(this.handleAuthResult.bind(this))
```

or for completeness, [naomik points out a third option which is quite elegant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35825873/157247): Using another arrow function:

```
this.authenticate(() => this.handleAuthRequest())
```

Comment: I see that you appended @naomik's solution here as well. Your response is overall very concise and explains why I was confused. I've accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

When you call

```
this.authenticate(this.handleAuthRequest);
```

The `this` becomes lost

You could do

```
this.authenticate(this.handleAuthRequest.bind(this));
```

Or

```
this.authenticate(() => this.handleAuthRequest());
```

Overall the code is pretty messy tho and a lot of parts don't make any sense to me. Specifically `callback({value: true})` is pretty weird. Anyway, If you have more specific questions, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Good point about your third option using another arrow function.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions. I agree that the code is messy, but it's actually a super simplified version of this JavaScript quickstart provided by Google where I replaced their functions with my own functions that took callbacks: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

Comment: Thanks @TJ. I often prefer to use another arrow function instead of leaning on `Function.prototype.bind`

Comment: A better use of arrow functions would be to put it directly on the class. Then it is always bound to the instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

in `checkAuth`, you should use

`this.authenticate(this.handleAuthResult.bind(this))`

that's because when calling `callback({value: true});` there is not `this` binded

Comment: Another way is to define callback methods as arrow functions, which, when applied to classes, are always bound to the class they are on. This question specifically asks about arrow functions.